# Multer destination file is not readable by ZEIT server

Tags: javascript, node.js, hosting, multer, vercel

I got the following error:  `no such as file or directory public/uploads/bae1774e-d6dc-454b-ba63-a4c8c53d3053.png` while I'm uploading an image to the server (nodejs) using [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) hosted through [ZEIT](https://zeit.co)

```
const multerMultiple = {
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, callback) => {
      callback(null, "./public/uploads"); // I think the problem here
    },
    filename: (req, file, callback) => {
      const extension = file.mimetype.split("/")[1];
      const name = `${uuid.v4()}.${extension}`;
      callback(null, name);
    }
  })
};
```

> The configuration above is working perfectly locally, while the node js is running locally

now.json

```
{
  "name": "application-name",
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    { "src": "index.js", "use": "@now/node-server" },
    { "src": "./public/uploads", "use": "@now/static" }
  ],
  "routes": [{ "src": "/.*", "dest": "/index.js" }],
  "env": {
    .../ env here
  }
}
```

Source View:

[image]

Which is mean the public directory is presented

So any idea why I'm getting the presented issue while the node js is hosted? It is something missing in ZEIT now configuration or something related to my code?

Comment: What is the error? You've only included a path to a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to upload files to your app, running as a lambda on Zeit.

Zeit works on top of AWS Lambda. AWS Lambda, and thus Now lambdas, offer only very limited writing to the filesystem during execution, but any changes will be lost when execution completes. There is no durability between lambda executions.

Instead, you'll need to write the files to some sort of durable storage, like AWS S3. Here's an example of how you might do that: https://github.com/zishon89us/node-cheat/tree/master/aws/express_multer_s3